# Vue2-Dropzone url endpoint error CORS error HeaderDisallowedByPreflightResponse

Tags: javascript, go, nuxt.js, dropzone.js, vue2-dropzone

i want to using [Vue2-Dropzone](https://github.com/rowanwins/vue-dropzone) for uploading multiple image/file. So i following the documentation and this is my options:

```
      options: {
        url: 'https://httpbin.org/post',
        autoProcessQueue: true,
        // thumbnailWidth: null,
        paramName: 'file',
        maxFilesize: 2,
        // formData: true,
        acceptedFiles: 'image/*', // Allow only image files
        addRemoveLinks: true // Show remove links on uploaded files
      },
```

but if i use `https://httpbin.org/post` sometimes (mostly often) there is an error failed. So i've been create endpoint for handle this in GO `https://myendpoint.com:9091/image/product`, but im facing new error ***CORS HeaderDisallowedByPreflightResponse***. I've allowed the cors and haven't used a bearer or anything else. I've tried in postman and running well. but when i try in localhost or production showing that error.

what should i do in my vue dropzone settings?

[image]

[image]

Comment: you've forgotten a very important piece of information in your question. What are the headers in your request? Clearly you're sending (at least) one that is not allowed by the pre-flight response you coded

Comment: i've been editing post above @JaromandaX

Comment: so, how does your preflight handler code look

Comment: i've been edited post above @JaromandaX